# How to include a CocoaPods framework only for certain schemes?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cocoapods

My app has three schemes, for each of my distribution channel:

[image]

- **Savings**: App Store
- **Savings Setapp**: Setapp
- **Savings Direct**: Developer ID signed distribution

Of these three, I want to include the Sparkle framework (for updating app) only for **Savings Direct**.

My Podfile looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, "Sparkle" is added to the target GreenBooks. I only have a single target:

[image]

What I want to do is for schemes other than "Savings Direct", exclude the Sparkle framework; that is, don't include in the app at all.

How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure it's absolutely required, but creating a separate target would be the standard CocoaPods usage way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Just need to specify build configuration (`configuration`) when inputting the Pod entry:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod